# Using the back button from a fragment in Android

Tags: android, android-fragments, onbackpressed

I'm aiming for the following behavior.

*When I am on my main activity,
If I navigate into fragment 1,
and from there, navigate into fragment 2,
then when I hit the phone's back button,
because I am on fragment 2 I am returned to the home screen, and not fragment 1.*

If I had a separate button on the page, this behavior would be very easy, as I could just do:

```
Button.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() 
{
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) 
    {
        FragmentManager fm = getFragmentManager();
        fm.popBackStack(null, FragmentManager.POP_BACK_STACK_INCLUSIVE);
    }
});
```

I'm running into difficulties because I need to use the phone's own back button. I've read that the OnButtonPressed() event is only usable by an activity, not a fragment, and moving this kind of logic into the activity is proving difficult!

**How can I achieve the behavior I'm after?**

Comment: Both answers were incredibly useful, taken together they gave me enough to get on the right course. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just track the backstackcount and you can do whatever you want on the basis of count :

```
    @Override
    public void onBackPressed() {
        manageBackStack();
    }

    private void manageBackStack() {
        switch (getSupportFragmentManager().getBackStackEntryCount()) {
            case 1:
                //Do when count is 1
                break;
            case 2:
                //Do when count is 2
                break;
            default:
                finish();
        }
    }
```

Hope it will help :)

Answer (score 1):

When you are adding the fragment you need to add the transaction to back stack. That means you want this transaction to be reversed when back button is pressed.

Please use the below code :

```
getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
                           .add(detailFragment, "detail")
                           // Add this transaction to the back stack
                           .addToBackStack()
                           .commit();
```

You can find more details in :

https://developer.android.com/training/implementing-navigation/temporal.html